# SQLAlchemy Join two tables in (1 to 0..1 ) relationship

Tags: python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy

I have these two tables in (1 to 0..1) relationship:

**models.py**

```
# --------------------------------------------------
class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)  

# --------------------------------------------------
class Gift(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'gift'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
    person = relationship("Person", uselist=False, backref="gift")

    gift_idea = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

# --------------------------------------------------
```

**Questions:**

1. Is the structure of my one to one  tables correct? I know that in the SQLAlchemy documentation, the relationship code line (person = relationship...) is in the parent class but I need it to be in the child class, is that OK?!
2. My goal is to display (gift_idea from Gift table) and (person_name, person_address from Person table), if there's a gift_idea for that person. In my search I found people use query.join to get that and I have tried many codes but this following statement at least get me half the content I
   need:

**views.py**

```
    a = session.query(Gift).join(Person)
```

Could you please assist me with my questions? Thank you for any effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In order to define proper 1-to-[0..1] relationship from the *child* side, you must make sure that the `backref` has `uselist=False` set, while the `uselist` from child to parent will be `False` by default:

   ```
   person = db.relationship(
       "Person",
       backref=db.backref("gift", uselist=False),
   )
   ```
2. Then the query is very straightforward to do:

   ```
   a = (session
        .query(
            Gift.gift_idea,
            Person.name.label("person_name"),
            Person.address.label("person_address"),
        )
        # .select_from(Gift)  # @note: optional, but will need it if the first column in the `.query(...)` above will be from table `Person`
        .join(Person)
        )
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As per sqlalchemy One to One relationship pattern definition ...

> One To One is essentially a bidirectional relationship with a scalar
>   attribute on both sides. To achieve this, the uselist flag indicates
>   the placement of a scalar attribute instead of a collection on the
>   “many” side of the relationship

In your case you've disabled "uselist" for Gifts by giving "uselist=False" (Actually by default it gets disabled). But you didn't disabled "uselist" for Persons. because of this Person can still hold list of Gifts (One person - Many Gifts).

You can get one to one mapping in two ways here..

1: By using `backref` function which provides arguments for the reverse side. keep your person as it is.

```
class Gift(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'gift'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
    person = relationship("Person", backref=backref("gift", uselist=False))

    gift_idea = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

2: Adding scalar attribute on both the sides instead of using backref property.

```
class Gift(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'gift'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
    gift_idea = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    person = relationship("Person")

# -----------------------------------------------

class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    gift = relationship("Gift", uselist=False)
```

**Solution for Question-2:**

@val: Gave you straightforward solution for this.. you could also try using lazy loading instead of clearly writing everything over orm query.

```
list_of_gift_object = session.query(Gift).join(Person).all()
```

may be you can iterate over the list and use Gift person attribute to get associated person data.

```
for gift in list_of_gift_object:
    print gift.gift_idea, gift.person.name, gift.person.address
```

Comment: I can't thank you enugh @gsb-eng, your explanation make sense of the code.
About your solution for Q2, I tried it, but it still print only one table data. The label in "van" code shows the data.

Comment: @Aseel It's interesting, I'm not sure how you've tried but if you still want to give it a try check this  (http://gsb-eng.com/solutions/one_to_one.html)

Comment: @Aseel BTW relationship are greatly used for lazy loading, checkout tips here (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/loading_relationships.html)

Comment: Thank you again @gsb-eng for your time and following up with me, I got many useful info from you since yesterday.

Now, after checking my code with yours, I found my mistake. In your print statement: `idea.person.name` and mine was { idea.name } missing the .person.!

Also after reading the page about lazy loading you gave me, I used this code instead `a = session.query(Gift).options(joinedload('person')).all()` and I like it better, makes my html template looks simpler.